# Standard way of doing a "thanks_for_downloading.html" + "Save file..." after a link?

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications, download

Let's look at FireFox.

They have a nice big Call To Action button: "Firefox 3.6 - Free Download"

You click that, it links you to a new page: "Thanks for downloading Firefox! Your download should begin in a few seconds."

Then a few seconds later up pops: "FIREFOX.exe - Do you want to save or discard this file?"

This is pretty standard download behavior for applications accross the web. How is it done, in the simplest way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two parts to this:

1. Forcing the browser to download the file, rather than trying to display it (with .exe that's no problem, but you might want to do it with an image, movie, or HTML file too).
2. Prompting the browser to download the file.

Let's pretend we just want the browser to download a file, without wanting to change the page. We can create a link like this, and it'll work as expected:

```
<a href="/download.zip">Download File</a>
```

Your browser probably doesn't know how to handle a zip file, so it downloads "download.zip" straight to a file named after the filename in the URL. If you wanted to download a JPG instead, though, this wouldn't work:

```
<a href="/images/sunset.jpg">Save this Sunset!</a>
```

Your browser knows how to display a JPEG, so it redirects the page and shows the JPEG. Now we need to tell the browser not to show it, but to download it instead. To do that, we have to send it some specific HTTP headers in the response from the server.

*Apache can handle this by specifying headers in .htaccess, but I'll stay away from a particular technology, opting to just talk about the mechanism.*

So we send the following header to the browser along with the image:

```
Content-disposition: attachment; filename=the_sunset_of_a_lifetime.jpg;
```

The first header, `content-disposition`, tells your browser that we want the file to be an attachment, or in other words, it should be saved, not displayed. The `filename` attribute tells it the name to use to save the file (rather than "sunset.jpg", the file will be named "the_sunset_of_a_lifetime.jpg").

Now the link to download the "sunset.jpg" file works like we want. But how do we get the browser to download it without the user clicking on the link so we can show a "Thank You" page and prompt the download to start? A simple `<meta>` tag can do the trick, telling the browser to redirect the page after a set period of time:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2;url=/images/sunset.jpg">
```

When your "thank you" page loads with that meta tag in the `head`, it'll wait for 2 seconds and then try to load the image. It'll get the headers we set in the last step, and download it instead of displaying it, and the user will stay put on the page like we want.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm a little unclear on this part: "So we send the following header to the browser along with the image..." Which file does that header go in? And where in that file?

Comment: HTTP Headers are sent by browser (Request Headers) and the server (Response Headers). If you're using Apache, you can create a directive that tells Apache to add an arbitrary header to a request for a particular file or directory. See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_headers.html for more info on that. You should create a separate question for help with creating that .htaccess/httpd.conf setup if you need it.

Comment: Ok. And the headers are only needed when dealing with files (like .jpgs) that the browser would normally just open, but you want to force a download instead? Are headers necessary for .exes and other non-browser file types? If I'm using a .exe, would just having the meta tag work?

Comment: Bingo. Sounds like you understand it. EXEs and other files a browser won't handle don't need any special handling on the server.

Answer (score 2):

Example content of `thanks_for_downloading.html`:

```
<strong>Thanks for downloading XY</strong>

<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function(){
    window.location.href = "path/to/XY.exe";
};
</script>
```

The Download-link is just a link to the thanks_for_downloading.html page

Comment: Cool, thanks. Nice and simple. Is there a pro/con to doing it this way as opposed to via (the other answer) of meta tags etc?

Comment: They are doing the same. If the user has JavaScript disabled, my method won't work, but the meta tag would do it.

Answer (score 1):

The call to action button is a regular link to the "Thank you" page.  Then on the "Thank you" page, use javascript to redirect the user to the file you are downloading by setting the "window.location" property to the file's URL.